# How not to resize a datagrid or a wrappanel item?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls, wrappanel

I have created a user control in which I have a datagrid along with other items.

One of the functionalities of these control is that through two buttons I can add or remove columns from the `DataGrid`.

Multiple of these controls are placed inside a `WrapPanel`, to display in my main application.

Now while running my application and I press the button to add a new column to the datagrid, the datagrid changes size and as result the initial user control becomes wider, which means that one of the childs of the wrappanel is wider than the other ones.
If I add multiple new lines and the user control reach the width of the application window then a scrollbar apprears below the datagrid so I can scroll and see all the contents in the datagrid.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Ideally I am looking for my wrappanel child to have a constant size, and my datagrid directly to present the scrollbar upon addition of a new column in it. Thus all the wrappanel childs have the same width.
I dont want to place a specific constant size to my user control if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve the same result with a `Grid` than with a `WrapPanel`, just a little bit less handy.

Starting from a grid you can set Width/MinWidth/MaxWidth (with star notation) and Height/.../... to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to set any width height information. Also with the wrappanel when changing size of the app window it will automatically rearrange the child elements in it, something that with a set grid can not happen.